# Complex normal Gaussian noise

Tags: noise, gaussian, random

I would like to create complex normal Gaussian noise with dimensions $(M,N)$. The noise should be zero mean and the variance should be equal to one.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the the standard formula:

```
s = randn(m, n) + 1i*randn(m, n);
```

And as pointed out by MBaz, the output should be scaled accordingly by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

```
s = s/sqrt(2);
```

More on that topic you can find for example in a book [Digital Media Processing by Hazarathaiah Malepati](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Digital-Media-Processing-Hazarathaiah-Malepati/dp/1856176789/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1437659551&sr=8-1&keywords=Digital+Media+Processing%3A+DSP+Algorithms+Using+C):

[image]

It should generate exactly what you want.

Comment: You'll have to scale by $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ to get unit variance in the complex case.

Comment: @David can you please explain why that is??

Comment: @DimitriC The variance of a complex RV is equal to the variance of its real part plus the variance of its imaginary part.